# Robocode: Where can I get a JAR file for the Engine?

Tags: java, jar, robocode

I wish to automatically run a series of Robocode tanks in matches, and recieve back their scores and other info.
I believe that I require the Robocode Engine, and wondered where I could get a JAR file for using it in Java.

Thanks!

Comment: http://sourceforge.net/projects/robocode/files/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have worked out the the Jar file that I need to use the methods from is actually inside the libs folder of the installed Robocode client. It's name is robocode.jar.
It just had to be added to the build path of my project as an external library